# Avoiding debugger halt using Transient Fault Handling Application Block

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-debugging, transient

I started using Transient Fault Handling Application Block (TFHAB) together with Azure Caching. It's easy to use but when in debugger, the error thrown within caching provider and passed out from TFHAB as not transient halts the debugger claiming 
'An exception of type 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException' occurred in MyLib.dll but was not handled in user code'
despite the fact that the call is wrapped in try/catch block. The code is like this:

```
UserData cacheItem;
try
{
    cacheItem = RetryPolicyFix.ExecuteAction(() => dataCache.GetAndLock(...) as UserData;
}
catch (DataCacheException e)
{
    if (e.ErrorCode == DataCacheErrorCode.ObjectLocked)
        ...
}
```

It is really annoying while debugging other parts of the code to be interrupted with these false halts.

I went through many discussions end ended up with workaround below.

```
UserData cacheItem;
try
{
    var res = RetryPolicyFix.ExecuteAction(
        () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var data = dataCache.GetAndLock(...) as UserData;
                    return new TFHResult(data);
                }
                catch (DataCacheException ex)
                {
                    // transient error should pass through as the TFHAB is responsible for its handling
                    if (RetryPolicyFix.ErrorDetectionStrategy.IsTransient(ex))
                        throw;
                    return new TFHResult(ex);
                }
            });

    if (res.Error != null)
        throw res.Error;

    cacheItem = res.Data;
}
catch (DataCacheException e)
{
    if (e.ErrorCode == DataCacheErrorCode.ObjectLocked)
        ...
}
```

The code uses helper struct:

```
private struct TFHResult
{
    public TFHResult(DataCacheException error)
    {
        Error = error;
        Data = null;
    }

    public TFHResult(UserDirectoryMappingData data)
    {
        Error = null;
        Data = data;
    }

    public DataCacheException Error;
    public UserDirectoryMappingData Data;
}
```

This solution is ugly and degrades the performance in runtime (without debugger attached) a bit and requires unnecessary more coding just to workaround the issue in debugger. I would be happy for community's opinion. Is there a better approach?